# What is the difference between Incoming webhook, Outgoing webhook and O365 webhook

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

Can anybody explain at a very basic level what is the difference between Incoming webhook, Outgoing webhook, and O365 webhook

Comment: It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors).

Comment: In short, (1) Webhooks is a lightweight HTTP pattern for connecting Web APIs & services with a publish/subscribe model. It's widely used in Microsoft Graph API world. (2) Outgoing webhooks allow your users to send text messages from a channel to your web services. Say, users can use @mention to your outgoing webhook & send a message to your service. (3) Incoming webhooks are the simplest type of connector used in your Microsoft Teams. For any channel in team  you can choose to expose an HTTPS endpoint that will accept JSON & insert messages into that channel. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Let me move this to answer. Consider upvoting it and accepting the answer; so it can be useful to other community members as well.

Answer (score 5):

- Webhooks is a lightweight HTTP pattern for connecting Web APIs & services with a publish/subscribe model. It's widely used in Microsoft Graph API world.
- Outgoing webhooks allow your users to send text messages from a
  channel to your web services. Say, users can use @mention to your
  outgoing webhook & send a message to your service.
- Incoming
  webhooks are the simplest type of connector used in your Microsoft
  Teams. For any channel in team you can choose to expose an HTTPS
  endpoint that will accept JSON & insert messages into that channel.
- It's documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/what-are-webhooks-and-connectors).

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is pretty accurate - webhooks are a lightweight API call - specifically known as an HTTP push request. Incoming webhooks are useful for triggering actions within your existing software application, database, etc. Outgoing webhooks can signal specified events to external applications, databases, etc. O365 provides opportunities to generate webhooks within several applications - more complex API calls are available via native development in the Azure programming interface.